# Conjugacy class of a semisimple element is closed

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

There are conjugacy classes in a topological group that are not closed. However I read that semisimple conjugacy classes are necessarily closed. Is there a simple argument to prove it? Is it valid for general topological groups or just for groups of a certain type?

Comment: What are semisimple conjugacy classes?

Comment: What is your definition of a semisimple element of a topological group? My definition would be that it is one whose conjugacy class is closed. Then in the case of, say, $SL(n,C)$ one can prove that an element is semisimple if and only if it is diagonalizable.